# Prevent Jenkins from Installing Artifact to Local Maven Repository

Tags: maven, hudson, jenkins, nexus, sonatype

Jenkins is installing the most-recently built artifact to the local Maven repository, even when the job is executed with a goal of only `clean package`.

This caused an issue when someone accidentally committed an updated version of a shared library without incrementing the version number in the library's POM. Jenkins built the jar, installed it to the local Maven repository, and then (as configured) deployed the artifact to our shared Nexus repository. Nexus quite rightly refuses to accept the new artifact, as it already has a release with the given version number.

Some time later Jenkins builds a project that depends on that library, and uses the copy of the library from its *local* Maven repository rather than Nexus. Thus the project got built with the wrong version of the code.

It seems there are two possible solutions:

1. Stop Jenkins from erroneously installing the .jar to the local
   repository
2. Prevent the local repository from being used when
   building projects that depend on the library

Answer (score 3):

It's the **install** goal that publishes to the local repository... So I've no answer for the first problem.

The second problem can be solved by isolating each build. Configure them to use their own local repositories so that mistakes in one don't affect others:

```
mvn -s settings.xml compile package
```

In the settings file declare unique path for the build job's local repository

```
<settings>
  <localRepository>/data/job1/repository</localRepository>
  ..
```

And it's probabily a good idea to periodically purge the local repositories, forcing clean builds.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in the Jenkins job configuration to use a private repository. This way you can avoid artefacts from your Jenkins build finding their way into your main repository. You need to open the extended options for the Maven build to see the option.

Comment: I've tried this, and sadly it makes no difference. I don't have the JIRA link handy, but I believe it's a known issue in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there is an option to actually use the (shared) local repository but turn off writing to it (i.e. deploy the artifacts only to the remote repository). This is to reduce the number of concurrent updates (but still keep sane disk usage:)

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent duplicate artifacts from being deployed in Nexus.  Each artifact should have a build number appended to avoid confusion.   Avoid SNAPSHOT versions as they cause headaches.

Comment: Thanks, but this question refers to the local repository, not a remote one.

Comment: My apologies - I read slightly too quickly.   Isolating local maven repositories per build seems like a more sensible approach in that case.  Each build should then be configured to only retrieve fully tested artifacts from a "release" repository.

This means good planning/communication when releasing common libraries for consumers.