# Setting Project specific maven repository

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have multiple projects. I want to create different maven repository paths for each project. Means, each project should point to different folder as maven repository (by default C:/Users/USERNAME/.m2 is used as repo).
I know that this may increase the download and same files if used in multiple projects will be downloaded/kept multiple times. But i want to separate out the repository for different projects so that i can bundle the repository along with my project's source code to be shared to the other person. I simply dont want to share my whole m2 repository (of size 2 gb) for a very small project sized 50 mb.

Regards,

Vibhav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your comments.

I finally did the following:

1. Setup each project as a separate workspace in eclipse
2. Created a separate apache maven folder for each project (actually duplicating the maven home even though i am using same version of maven)
3. From eclipse workspace, I pointed out the appropriate maven home
4. configured the repository path (localRepository) in MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml file from default ~./m2/repository to something like MAVEN_HOME/repo

This way, I could get separate maven repositories for each project (or I should say workspace).

Thanks,
Vibhav Agrawal

Answer (score 4):

You can specify repository location via command line option `-Dmaven.repo.local=`

I'd have just put a wrapper script to start maven in the project location and specified repository in it (probably pointing to location inside the project for your use case).

Answer (score 0):

See the following answer:

[Prevent Jenkins from Installing Artifact to Local Maven Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582271/prevent-jenkins-from-installing-artifact-to-local-maven-repository/7587606#7587606)

In a nutshell use a settings file for each build. Enables you to control both the local repository used for that project, but also other settings like repositories and build profiles.

Comment: Does this fix Eclipse's uneditable M2_HOME classpath variable?

Comment: @JoeCoder Unrelated I think. The M2_HOME within Eclipse is effectively whereever your Maven installation is located. "Preferences->Maven->Installations". You global settings file is similarily specified under "Preferences->Maven->User Settings". In the settings file you can decide (using localRepository tag) where Maven will store it's downloaded file. So from my perspective M2_HOME doesn't really matter.

Comment: I agree that is normally true, but I have multiple maven repositories and `mvn eclipse:eclipse` always generates a .classpath using the M2_HOME variable.  When that variable is not modifiable on the Project level, I cannot compile two Projects using different repos in the same Workspace at the same time without manually editing .classpath.

Comment: @JoeCoder Ahh, now I get you..... I seem similar complaints from ANT users trying to sync their classpaths with the .classpath file.... I suppose your only hope is to write a custom Maven plugin to replace the standard eclipse one. In fairness the assumptions made by Eclipse are not unreasonable.... Are you using a Maven repository to hold you project specific files? Ideally your local repo should act more like a cache rather than a repository

Comment: Problem solved by creating a separate dev environment and syncing non-generated resources by SVN.  I guess the rigid tool options helped me not setup a bad situation.  Thanks for your comments, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

My solution using Eclipse and Maven is to create new workspace, maven repository and settings.xml replacing the default .m2 repository path.

[your new settings.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IkJR.png)

Then, try in Eclipse: Preferences>User Settings and browse your settings.xml

[replace the User Settings file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErkZL.png)