# jenkins maven repository configuration

Tags: maven, repository, jenkins

I am new to maven and Jenkins, I am trying to build a maven 3 project.
I have maven in c drive and I moved the repository to d drive. 
But when I configure a build in Jenkins, it is creating its own repository(I think so)
Now How to configure jenkis, so that it can use my repository in D drive.

Hope I made sense.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582271/prevent-jenkins-from-installing-artifact-to-local-maven-repository/7587606#7587606

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to adjust the settings.xml to point out which repository to use.

```
<localRepository>C:\\USER_LOCAL_DIR\.m2\m2repository</localRepository>
```

where `USER_LOCAL_DIR` is your user directory (e.g. `Users\your_user_name`).

Further more you should make sure which `settings.xml` the maven is using, if you dont have any specific user settings.xml the maven will start using the settings.xml which is at maven configuration directory, which will be `M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml` (`M2_HOME` being the Maven home directory). The hierarchy for `settings.xml` is first the user `.m2` directory and if it could not find that, it will try to find the one in `M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check for settings.xml file under

1. ..\maven-xx\conf\settings.xml file
2. C:\Users\Username.m2\settings.xml file

You may need to remember precedence in the order mentioned. In case if you need to point to a private maven repository consider to check both the files and in case if it's not pointing to intended location then update the settings file accordingly.