# How resolve dependencies from multiple local maven repositories

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to figure out the optimum way to use maven on a CI server that has hundreds of jobs most more or less related to each other that use a lot of the same common libraries, plugins, etc.  They are all run by the same user, so by default they all share the same repo at `~/.m2/repository`.  However, on a build server this is bad--especially when many multi-module builds need to perform a `mvn install` so that post build steps will work correctly, *post builds steps that may ultimately fail the build and decide not to do `mvn deploy`.*

What I think I want is something like how eclipse works, or how mutli-module projects work with a single reactor run--you can resolve all the dependencies without them actually being installed.  Short of that, I would like to have two sets of local repositories, one from which to resolve all deployed packages and one into which I can install the current builds artifacts such that post build steps can resolve dependencies from both giving priority to the latter.

All of this said, what I am really interested in is a working solution whether it works along these lines or not, for the requirements of needing to do local installs but not wanting every job to have its own full repo (due to the tremendous file system bloat that would entail--a single repo could be in excess of 2GB even with all old snapshots cleaned out).

It seems this would be a common problem and that a lot of busy CI servers would encounter and that there would at least one typical solution, but I can't seem to find anything.  Suggestions?

Comment: Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Jenkins from Installing Artifact to Local Maven Repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582271/prevent-jenkins-from-installing-artifact-to-local-maven-repository)

Comment: We are using maven 3